# Apache mod_proxy_ajp with GlassFish thread pool busy

Tags: apache, glassfish-3, mod-proxy

I've got Apache 2.2.15 proxying requests to GlassFish 3.1.1 via mod_proxy_ajp using the defaults on both Apache and GlassFish.  The setup seems to work okay for a very short while then I'll get a thread pool busy error message in the GlassFish log followed by a timeout error in the Apache log and the application doesn't work again until I restart GlassFish.

Should I make configuration changes to prevent this error?

Note: the system is not under heavy load - it is just accessed by myself with one browser by navigating through pages in the application.  This suggests the issue might be a thread leak bug if it isn't a misconfiguration.  The error I get in the browser is 500: Internal Server Error.

The error in the GlassFish log is:

```
SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|threadpool.busy
```

The error in the Apache log is:

```
[error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
```

My proxy configuration in Apache is:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
ProxyPass / ajp://mydomain:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://mydomain:8009/
```

And in GlassFish I just run the following commands after the install:

```
asadmin create-http-listener --listenerport 8009 --listeneraddress 0.0.0.0 --defaultvs server apache-proxy
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.apache-proxy.jk-enabled=true
```

Comment: I found this link today: [mod_jk post on java.net](http://www.java.net/node/701914), which suggests the problem is the thread pool default max size it too small.  I increased the size to 50 and haven't been able to reproduce the crash yet.  I'm not confident that I'm not just delaying the inevitable crash though. Still looking for re-assuring answers and maybe tips on how to convince myself this setup is okay for production use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question on the GlassFish forum on java.net and got a response of the effect:

> You must ensure that GlassFish's maximum threads is at least as many as Apache.

Full Answer here:

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/jkenabled-thread-leak

This seems like a reasonable answer so I'm posting it here for the benefit of others.

Note: one way to set the threads used on Apache is to use the *max* attribute like so:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://mydomain:8009/ max=20
```

Comment: For Apache Prefork MPM I think setting the max-thread-pool-size on GlassFish might be more appropriate? asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.thread-pools.thread-pool.http-thread-pool.max-thread-pool-size=50

Comment: To clarify: with Prefork MPM it seems there is always 1 AJP thread per process.  So it looks like you would have to change the Apache MaxClients/ServerLimit to be smaller or make glassfish pool size larger (default Apache MaxClients is 256)!  Or use the ProxyPass disablereuse parameter.  Or maybe a small ProxyPass ttl parameter will cause releasing of resources?